# Calculate the percentage of the value in the column after grouping with 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have the following data frame:

|  | Date | Cost | Corporate | Vehicle type | Price | Insurance | Date_M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-08-26 04:14:00 | 23719 | 0 | automobile | 25903 | 1 | 2019-08 |
| 1 | 2020-08-27 01:21:03 | 17159 | 0 | truck | 24748 | 1 | 2020-08 |
| 2 | 2019-08-26 18:49:04 | 3629 | 0 | truck | 11777 | 0 | 2019-08 |
| 3 | 2020-08-31 16:57:02 | 50738 | 1 | automobile | 51296 | 0 | 2020-08 |
| 4 | 2020-08-23 14:48:02 | 48173 | 0 | truck | 56314 | 0 | 2020-08 |

---

```
data = {
    "Date": [
        "2019-08-26 04:14:00",
        "2020-08-27 01:21:03",
        "2019-08-26 18:49:04",
        "2020-08-31 16:57:02",
        "2020-08-23 14:48:02",
    ],
    "Cost": [23719, 17159, 3629, 50738, 48173],
    "Corporate": [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    "Vehicle type": ["automobile", "truck", "truck", "automobile", "truck"],
    "Price": [25903, 24748, 11777, 51296, 56314],
    "Insurance": [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    "Date_M": ["2019-08", "2020-08", "2019-08", "2020-08", "2020-08"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

no_insurance = df['Insurance'] == 0
df_no_insurance = df[no_insurance]
results = pd.DataFrame()
df_group = df_no_insurance.groupby((['Date_M','Corporate']))
results['Number of cars'] = df_group['Date'].count()
results['Доходность'] = np.round((df_group['Price'].sum() - df_group['Cost'].sum())/df_group['Price'].sum() * 100, 2)
```

Results

Here's how those appear on the console

|  |  | numbers of cars | profitability |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data_M | Corporate |  |  |
| 2019-04 | 0 | 61 | 10.10 |
|  | 1 | 53 | 7.36 |
| 2019-05 | 0 | 68 | 8.44 |
|  | 1 | 68 | 8.61 |

How can I calculate % of trucks and insert it into a new column of results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, got it!

Hope this solves your problem,

```
results['Percentage of Trucks'] = df_group.apply(lambda x: (x['Vehicle type'] == 'truck').sum() / len(x) * 100)
```

This code returns the result as,

```
                  Number of cars  Доходность  Percentage of Trucks
Date_M  Corporate
2019-08 0                       1       69.19                 100.0
2020-08 0                       1       14.46                 100.0
        1                       1        1.09                 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what you already have, just filter `df_no_insurance` to keep only trucks:

```
results["Number of trucks"] = (
    df_no_insurance.loc[df_no_insurance["Vehicle type"] == "truck"]
    .groupby((["Date_M", "Corporate"]))["Date"]
    .count()
)
results["Number of trucks"] = results["Number of trucks"].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Result:

```
                   Number of cars  Доходность  Number of trucks
Date_M  Corporate                                              
2019-08 0                       1       69.19                 1
2020-08 0                       1       14.46                 1
        1                       1        1.09                 0
```

Answer (score -1):

By adding this you will be able to get the % of trucks in a new column.

```
results['Percentage of Trucks'] = df_group['Vehicle type'].transform(lambda x: (x == 'truck').sum() / len(x) * 100)
```

So, here's how your code should be modified,

```
no_insurance = df['Insurance'] == 0
df_no_insurance = df[no_insurance]
results = pd.DataFrame()
df_group = df_no_insurance.groupby((['Date_M','Corporate']))
results['Number of cars'] = df_group['Date'].count()
results['Доходность'] = np.round((df_group['Price'].sum() - df_group['Cost'].sum())/df_group['Price'].sum() * 100, 2)
results['Percentage of Trucks'] = df_group['Vehicle type'].transform(lambda x: (x == 'truck').sum() / len(x) * 100)
```

Comment: But all new colums returns NaN